# Change Pusher Channel lifetime using Javascript API

Tags: javascript, comet, pusher

How to change a channel connection lifetime in [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) Javascript API when initializing a connection?

I want to connection for a given client to automatically disconnect after 30 seconds when user is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just provided you with an answer via the ticketing system.

You will find info here: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#activitytimeout-integer

Regards
Loic